# ruby dump object to html formatted string

Tags: html, ruby, pretty-print, cfdump

Is there a ruby equivalent of ColdFusions cfdump tag.

which can dump any object as a html formatted output.

I want to use this to be able to dump any object into an email html body.

I know there is Pretty Print and other gems out there that output colour coded well formatted strings to the console, but I want to be able to generate a html string, dumping out the entire data type I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [CodeRay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) colorizer.

```
CodeRay.scan("5.times do\n  puts 'Hello, world!'\nend", :ruby).
        div(:line_numbers => :table)
```

I use it to highlight JSON snippets in my wiki, so if you pretty print objects to JSON and then pass it through coderay, it'll certainly work.

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

The [rails-cfdump](http://code.google.com/p/rails-cfdump/) project is abandoned, but it looks like its output is very similar to CF's `<cfdump>`/`WriteDump()`.

Answer (score 0):

The [dom](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) gem that I have developed lets you write HTML string from Ruby code. Using it, you can do things like:

```
require "dom"
["foo".dom(:span, class: "bold"), "bar"].dom(:div).dom(:body).dom(:html)
# => "<html><body><div><span class=\"bold\">foo</span>bar</div></body></html>"
```

Comment: This bottom-up approach is... unusual. How well do you find it works in practice? Never seen one in the wild.